# Transparent background of nsviewcontroller with controlls on it

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, transparent, nsviewcontroller

We were trying to create an app with non-rectangular window.

Our first idea was to hide the default "grey area" of window, and display a non rectangular image on top of that view controller (which would be the background). Then have a buttons on that in order to control it.

Our problem now is to make the view controller's background transparent. Any ideas/examples how to do that?

We have found how to change the background color with layers, but nothing about transparency of background while keeping of all the controls on it:

```
[self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
[self.view.layer setBackgroundColor:[[NSColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually, not exactly, in that example when you do change the transparency, it also hides a control on view, while I want to change transparency of background, and preserve all the controls on view visible.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself what has helped me.
If somebody is interested in the same, here is what I was looking for:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html